# EditText field is too large or overwritten

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I format a header, a list, and an EditText so that the EditText is a fixed single line and always visible?
Here is my layout with only one list entry - EditText fills the rest of the screen which looks bad.
[image]

Here is the layout with several list entries - the soft keyboard hides the text being typed. I was typing in Wayne.
[image]

I have tried a various Linear and Relative layouts.  Here is my current Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/select_child_header"
    style="@style/headerStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/start_blue"
    android:text="Which child did you take a picture of?" />

<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/modchild_fragment"
    android:name="com.chex.control.ChildList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/select_child_header"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
</fragment>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/new_child"
    style="@style/editTextStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_below="@id/modchild_fragment" 
    android:hint="new child name"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:singleLine="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I appreciate any advice on how to format this screen.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have a two options one is In textview there is a tag called `android:singleLine="true"` if you do like this the text comes in a single line and it miss the some text and show some dots..

And another way is you have to decrease the fontsize.. by using this tag..`android:textSize="3sp"`

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
 android:maxLines="1"
```

to your EditText, to get  desired  number of lines .

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/select_child_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Which child did you take a picture of?" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/modchild_fragment"
        android:name="com.chex.control.ChildList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
    </fragment>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/new_child"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/modchild_fragment"
        android:hint="new child name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
android:ellipsize=end  
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the order and positioning of your elements:

1. add first the header on top
2. add the bottom edittext
3. add the fragment in-between

Something like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/select_child_header"
        style="@style/headerStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/start_blue"
        android:text="Which child did you take a picture of?" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/new_child"
        style="@style/editTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:hint="new child name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/modchild_fragment"
        android:name="com.chex.control.ChildList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/new_child"
        android:layout_below="@id/select_child_header"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
    </fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the static height to the Fragment. So that if your list item say for example, one or more than 5 also, your edit text constitutes the bottom layer of fragment. 
Also, you can set android:singleLine="true" property to edittext.